# Prevent a paragraph break before a section heading

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

How can I prevent a paragraph break *before* a section heading? To prevent it *after*, I know that I can use `runin` like

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large\bf}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{}
```

However, how can I prevent *before*?  I want something like:

**1. First section heading** *Text...* (no line break here) **2. Second Section Heading** *Text...*

---

EDIT.   I am trying in the following way for `\subsection`. I created a new command like:

```
\newcommand{\subsectionnlb}[1]{
   \stepcounter{subsection}
   {\normalfont\bf\thesubsection \hspace{0.3em} #1\hspace{0.3em}}
}
```

How can I call the formatting of `\subsection` and apply to the custom command `\subsectionnlb`?

Comment: If I understood, you want something like **1. First section heading** _Text... and then comes a section heading without a line break_ **2. Second Section Heading** _Text..._ If so, `titlesec` package can't do it, because the very `\section` command internals (namely, as far as I know, `\@startsection`) definition starts with a `\par`...

Comment: @henrique You are correct. I revised my question. What about a `\subsection` without break?

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be more close to a list (more specifically `trivlist``) than to real sectioning : And the accepted answer reinforce this feeling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use `\section` specifically, you can try the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcounter{sect}%          Creates a counter to be used in the new section command
\newcommand\Section[1]{%    Defines a new section command:
 \addtocounter{sect}{1}%    Increases counter
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\arabic{sect}.~#1}% Add to table of contents
  {\sectfont% This command is intended to use with scrartcl class; 
%    if not using it you can use any formatting command you wish
  \arabic{sect}.~#1.}}%    Prints "<section number>. <section title>"
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blindtext
\Section{A first section}
\blindtext
\Section{A second section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: BTW, this workaround doesn't use (it's actually incompatible with) `titlesec` package, but I assumed (based on your last comment) that you didn't actually required it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I don't need `titlesec`, so I deleted it from the title. 

I was wondering if there is something similar to `\sectfont` in the `article` package.

Comment: There isn't --- the definition of `\section` in _article.cls_ is `\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`. If you'll use this workaround you can create one with `\newcommand{\sectfont}{\bfseries}` for example. I don't recommend changing the font size, as the sectioning command will come within the text.